# Apparent rotation of a wheel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A wheel with 16 spokes rotating in the clockwise direction is photographed on film, The is passed through a projector at the rate of 24 frames/s, which is the proper rate for the projector. On the screen, however, the wheel appears to rotate counterclockwise at 4.0 rev/min, Find the smallest possible angular speed at which the wheel was rotating.

I have come to say that a ray in apparent motion travels a certain angle, but how can I pass to real motion? Shouldn't it be 360 ​​degrees minus that angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After $1/24$ sec, the wheel will rotate far enough that the next spoke will move not quite to where the current spoke is. That is, the wheel rotates not quite $1/16$ revolutions = $22.5^o$ in $1/24$ sec.

The shortfall is enough that the wheel appears to rotate backward $4$ revolutions in $60$ sec, or $4/60$ revolution in $1$ sec, or $4/(60*24)$ revolutions $= 1/360$ revolutions = $1^o$ in $1/24$ sec.

The wheel rotates $21.5^o$ in $1/24$ sec. Or $516^o$ per sec. Or $1.4333$ revolutions per sec.